# Source for not having picture taken

Tags: minhag, technology, sources-mekorot, symbols-symbology

Is there any source, halachic or otherwise, for an aversion to having one's picture taken?

Comment: Why might you think so: what makes you ask: what's the basis for your question? (Don't answer me here in the comments: edit it in to the question!)

Answer (score 10):

Rav Ovadia Yosef Shelit"a (Yehawe Daat 3:63) brings the ישכיל עבדי חלק ב' בקונטרס אחרון חלק יורה דעה סימן י that based on the Zohar and the Ari one shouldn't get his picture taken.

Comment: ,it is interesting that Sod Yesharim holds its mutar.

Comment: Ironic, considering your profile picture.

Comment: Something about hating the player, not the game @ezra

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Honestly not sure I understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 5):

The Gemora ([Rosh Hashana 24b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=24b&format=pdf), [Avoda Zara 43b](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue8.pdf)) writes that one may not make a portrait of a human. The Rishonim argue whether this refers to only protruding images (such as a sculpture) or extends to non protruding images such as photos and drawings. Shulchan Aruch ([YD 141:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=126)) follows the opinion of Tosfos ([Azoda Zara 43b "Vehu"](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue8.pdf)) that it only refers to protruding images, however the [Tur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14267&st=&pgnum=468) there quotes the opinion of the Ramban who is forbids even non-protruding images.

According to the opinion that the prohibitions includes non-protruding images of people, one would not be allowed to take pictures of people ([Maharam Shick YD 170](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1495&st=&pgnum=111), [Zekan Aaron 2:47](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=834&pgnum=66), Am Hatorah 3:5 page 59). Based on this opinion, some people are careful not to have their pictures taken, and do not hang pictures of people in their homes. ([Da’as Kohen YD 66](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20315&st=&pgnum=169), [Divrei Malkiel 3:58](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=804&pgnum=83), Levushei Mordechai YD 1:86, [Darchei Teshuva 141:35](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14570&st=&pgnum=268&hilite=), Nemukei Orach Chaim 243 page 112 (old), [Yaskil Avdi YD 2:11 Kuntres Achron](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=960&st=&pgnum=240&hilite=), [Vayivorech Dovid 1:100](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9755&st=&pgnum=333), Maseei Ish 1:page 29:33, [Teshuvos V’hanhugos 3:263](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&st=&pgnum=294), see [Shevet Ha’Levi 7:134:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1417&pgnum=145) who is unsure).

See [this](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue8.pdf) edition of Halachically Speaking for more on the subject. [There is what to rely on the be lenient, the question asked for a source for being strict.]

Comment: ...because of lifnei iver? Why extend from the taker to the takee?

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess, I'll try to look up and link to the sources but hebrewbooks.org access atm is not too good

Comment: Actually it's not even the taker but the developer/printer who has the real problem.

Comment: @DoubleAA The linked article did bring the idea that we can be lenient if it is a gentile developing. The question asked for sources not to have your picture taken.

Comment: Yes, I'm just pointing out that the Lifnei Iver would actually be another stepped removed from the one whose picture is being taken.