# Can you take and post pictures of people online without their permission?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, internet, writing-printing, pictures

Realizing that there is some concern with [having one's picture taken](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14874/source-for-not-having-picture-taken/) in the first place; according to those who allow pictures of people to be taken, is there any halachic reason which would prevent one from taking pictures of people in public (ie in a way which breaks no civil law) and sharing those pictures either online or in print without getting the expressed permission of those in the picture?

Comment: with regards to the concept of '*umdena*' or '*stam daas*', I would assume everyone now-a-days realizes the ramifications of having their picture taken that it will made available in some sort of media...

Answer (score 3):

[Rav Moshe Heinemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Heinemann) answered in a shiur,

> If you just photograph someone else, and won’t show the picture to
>   others, then I don’t see a way for someone to be makpid – he’s
>   standing there for everyone to see right now. However, if you will
>   show the picture to others, then perhaps the individual would be
>   makpid to not have his picture taken. For instance, someone might be
>   walking on a street which he wouldn’t want his in-laws in a different
>   state to see him walking on. If the person being photographed is in a
>   private location, then you certainly need his permission. Nonetheless,
>   if you entered a building seeing there was a camera taking pictures,
>   then you can’t say you are makpid to not have the pictures available
>   for others since you put yourself into the position to have your
>   picture taken. Therefore, the owner of the camera would be allowed to
>   use your photograph.